# Security: In General, is Using Content-Type Enough to Prevent CSRF?

Tags: security, csrf, csrf-protection

As the question asks, I have a generic website using Jetty and I'm being asked for CSRF protection.

If I have a form:

```
<form action="http://somedomain.com/somepage">
    <input ....>
</form>
```

My question:  If somepage only accepts content-type:  application/json, is this enough to prevent CSRF?  I am sure I have to generate a unique token per user.  However, how would someone be able to violate CSRF if only protection is done by way of content-type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Probably

Long answer: Don't bank on it.

See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10231) for a more complete explanation, but while content type checking works *today*, you can get pretty close by posting valid JSON as text/plain which may be incorrectly parsed by some backends.

Additionally, if `enctype='application/json'` ever becomes valid HTML, your whole system is pooched.

While it's a great first step, if you really want to protect against CSRF attacks, implement a proper CSRF token system.

Comment: Late addition, because this response seems to popup with a high Google score...:  first part of the answer is a valid warning, however "enctype=application/json" is supposed to use same-origin restrictions, at least according to spec.

Comment: Yeah, my point was more than relying on well-behaved clients rather than known a well-behaved server puts you in a position of potential vulnerability.

Comment: While we're making late additions, and on the subject of well-behaved clients, the W3C Beacon spec had a specification vulnerability open for quite a while that made Content-Type insufficient. Chrome had a vulnerable implementation - I'm not sure about other browsers. https://github.com/w3c/beacon/issues/16